# the prep 'when' in the perfect tense

Tags: grammar, tenses

1. This room had been cleaned when the last tenant moved out.
2. This room has been cleaned when the last tenant moved out.

Are the two sentences correct? If they are, I want to make sure that the difference between the sentences is cleaning the room before and after moving out.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

"Has been cleaned" implies that the cleaning was recent and the room is still clean.

"Had been cleaned" implies that the room was clean at the time being referred to (but could have got dirty since).

We would assume that the cleaning happened after the tenant left, but neither sentence says so definitively. You would have to say "had already been cleaned" if it happened before.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I fixed it.「This room had already been cleaned by the last tenant when he moved out.」

Answer (score 1):

The second is not idiomatic: we don't use the present perfect with an expressed *point* in time. We can use it with a *period* of time, including that expressed by "since", so:

> This room has been cleaned since the last tenant moved out.

is fine.

Sentence 1 is fine: the past perfect does not have that restriction.

But, as Kate Bunting says, neither makes clear whether the cleaning was before or after the moving out. An alternative to her suggestion is

> The room had been cleaned before the last tenant moved out.

The simple past "was cleaned" would also be possible here, the difference being on whether the speaker was choosing to put temporal focus on the moving out or not.

Comment: Well, we don't use the present perfect with *any* past time expression, point or period, but we can use it with *now* or expressions that include *now* (*today, this year* etc.)

Comment: ... expressions referring to periods that include now ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, to the point *now* or to periods that include *now*. --> *But now the room has been cleaned*. And other expressions that have a similar meaning to the point *now*. E.g. *At this point in time we've been able to keep up with everything that's been thrown at us* etc. The description is misleading.

Comment: _This afternoon_ is not an expression that includes _now_; the period referenced may or may not include 'now' (= 'the moment the string _this afternoon_ was spoken / written / thought ...'). //// _The here and now_ **is** an expression that includes _now_.

Comment: @Araucaria You seem to have forgotten that italicising _now_ indicates a mention usage.

Comment: @Araucaria So you're happy to be ambiguous.